# To load .m matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to read data from a .m MATLAB file which is saved in my directory. However, when I used `load('filename.m')`, I get is a structure of size 1*1 and the 3320*9 matrix is within that structure file. How can I read it directly as a 3320*9 matrix?

Comment: An M-file is for code, not for data. How did you make this file? If it actually is a script that creates a variable with data, then just run it saying `filename` (without the `.m`).

Comment: Basically I want to store the matrix which is generated as an output in a directory so that I can use it as an input for a Matlab program later. So I stored it using 'save' command. But I think that is not the way. Can you Please tell me how can I store the output as a matrix so that I can use it later ( And what command I should use to load it back ? )

Comment: Provided at least part of your code so we could try to help you. As @CrisLuengo stated, the `.m` extension is for code. Data is stored in a `.mat` file. Check the differences [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/27048-difference-between-m-and-mat-files)

Comment: Z = zeros(1380,9);        
 for i=1:1380    
    for j=1:9;    
    fullpath =  'C:\\ALL FOLDERS\\DATA_SET\\Test_Set_All\\';   
    filename = imread(sprintf([fullpath  '\\fig_ (%d).jpg'],i));       
     Z(i,j) = A; % A is the coutput of some calculation the code is not shown here      
    end   
 end
  % I want to store the value of 'Z' on a folder and I want to use that
  % Matrix later in another program 
save('Z'); % Save Z does not store the matrix Z
% I want to store Z as 1380*9 matrix

Comment: @sollybennet please add your code to the question body by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57924661/edit) your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired behavior, if you're allowed to modify your save function.

```
Z = rand(10)
save('test.dat','Z','-ascii')
```

The ascii format is key, because Matlab allows a load directly to a variable:

```
test = load('test.dat','Z')
```

[image]